# Rendering a QGraphicsScene to QImage results in objects being placed on a side of QImage

Tags: c++, image, qt

My `QGraphicsScene` is quite large, and the `QGraphicsView` will only fit a small portion of it.

I would like to print/save the `QGraphicsScene`

```
OutputView::OutputView(QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent) {...}

void OutputView::saveToImage() 
{
    QImage image(scene()->sceneRect().size().toSize(), QImage::Format_Mono);
    image.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter painter(&image);
    render(&painter);
    image.save("output.png");
}
```

Of course as I am experimenting, I am placing objects in the center of the viewport...

The saved image contains all the objects, but the location of the objects is on the left side of the image

input:
[image]

output:
[image]
(screenshot from windows photo viewer)

It seems that an image is created with the correct size, but then only the viewport contents are rendered - with top left corner of the viewport on the top left corner of the image, leaving the rest of the image empty.

Why is this happening ? what am I doing wrong ?

Update:

Trying

```
fitInView(scene()->sceneRect());
```

results in the viewport showing the entire image, zoomed ... but the saved image still contains the viewport (only very tiny)

[image]

Comment: scene()->sceneRect().size() returns a QRectF, what does the toSize() function do? It's not a member of QRectF, according to the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf-members.html

Comment: Returns a QSize (from QSizeF)....... The sizes are correct, I have qDebug tested them

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. I see it now. If you call QGraphicsView::fitInView first, does it do the same?

Comment: I just tried, and the viewport is showing the zoomed image but the output is still the same (actually skewed because i ignored aspect ratio). I will add screenshot

Comment: And if you don't use the mono image format?

Comment: the color makes no difference - but as I was editing my question to respond to you I figured it out, thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, it often helps just to talk things through ;O)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer was in my additional explanation.

I should have done

```
scene()->render(&painter);
```

I was rendering the viewport.... not the scene